# How to share html report of pytest-html with out changing the css

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest-html

I am using python 3.6 and pytest-html to generate HTML reports .
Everything is successfully working but when i share my html report to my manager the css of the entire document is out of placed .can someone tell the reason to why it is happening and the solution for it .

The view of reports when i run:[image]

The view of the reports when i share the document with my manager
[image]

Comment: Both HTML files are different. Are you sure you are sharing correct files?

Comment: ok sorry , ill try to change it know ,but the end result is same only

Comment: i mean with respect to how the HTML reports display

Comment: How are you saving the report HTML?

Comment: when i write a script ,it will generate the HTML report  and save in .html format

Comment: Do you see only HTML file or HTML files and other folders/files created when you save it in your system.?

Comment: html file and other folder/file i see

Comment: Send those file and folders along with HTML and see

Comment: if i send folders along with HTML it will work but by lead is like i should send only HTML report it seems nothing else

Comment: then you can place the css code inside the html file which you can send

Comment: tried that also still same problem

Comment: i got the solution @Prany thank you for your constant reply ,

Comment: what is the solution, can you share for future use. Is it same placing css inside same file ?

Comment: yup thats the one

Comment: cool I am putting that into answers and then you can mark it as an answer for future purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are not sharing whole bunch of items like CSS with html file you are giving. Just place the CSS code inside your HTML rather than giving the path and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

include --self-contained-html when you are calling your pytest...such as 
pytest your.pyfilename --html=pathandfilename --self-contained-html.

Your result file have inline css in it.

Answer (score 1):

html=report.html --self-contained-html